# HTML link doesn't work on ipad/safari

Tags: html, ipad, safari

I'm using this code

```
<a data-idx="rx" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle show-visor-popup" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
    <img class="some-image" src="# ../>
    <h4> some text </h4>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu hide-content-for-popup" role="menu" id="rx">
 ...
```

for a image+text, when you click on it, a new dropdown menu opens. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not in iPad or Safari (the click doesn't work, like the `<a>` was ignored).

Comment: What ios safari version? HTML5 custom data attributes can be used from 9.3. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset

Comment: i have Safari/600.1.4

Comment: that was the problem, the version of the safari. thx a lot!